# OAuthWebSecurity with Facebook not using email permission as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

Using the new OAuthWebSecurity for authenticating with Facebook, I added the email permission on my Facebook application. Now, as I can read, I need to define a scope to be able to actually get the email in the result. So far without the scope I'm not getting the users' email and am not sure why as I can not see where to define the "scope".

It's just a rip of the [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 4 default authenticationcontrollers external login.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx

Answer (score 21):

Firstly, the extraData parameter is not passed to facebook. It is for internal use only. See the following link on how this data can be used on your site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/24/customizing-the-login-ui-when-using-oauth-openid.aspx

Now, to the meat:

In addition to the methods `RegisterFacebookClient`, `RegisterYahooClient` etc. in `OAuthWebSecurity`, there is also a generic method `RegisterClient`. This is the method we will be using for this solution.

This idea germinates from the code provided at:
http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/Facebook-Twitter/MVC-4-oAuth-Facebook-Login-EMail-Problem-Solved.html

However, we will not be using the hacky approach provided by the solution. Instead, we will create a new class called `FacebookScopedClient` which will implement `IAuthenticationClient`. Then we will simply register the class using:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookScopedClient("your_app_id", "your_app_secret"), "Facebook", null);
```

in AuthConfig.cs

The code for the class is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

    public class FacebookScopedClient : IAuthenticationClient
        {
            private string appId;
            private string appSecret;

            private const string baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=";
            public const string graphApiToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
            public const string graphApiMe = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";


            private static string GetHTML(string URL)
            {
                string connectionString = URL;

                try
                {
                    System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
                    myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    //// Get the response
                    WebResponse webResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
                    Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    ////
                    StreamReader ioStream = new StreamReader(respStream);
                    string pageContent = ioStream.ReadToEnd();
                    //// Close streams
                    ioStream.Close();
                    respStream.Close();
                    return pageContent;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                return null;
            }

            private  IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessCode, string redirectURI)
            {

                string token = GetHTML(graphApiToken + "client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURI) + "&client_secret=" + appSecret + "&code=" + accessCode);
                if (token == null || token == "")
                {
                    return null;
                }
                string data = GetHTML(graphApiMe + "fields=id,name,email,gender,link&access_token=" + token.Substring("access_token=", "&"));

                // this dictionary must contains
                Dictionary<string, string> userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
                return userData;
            }

            public FacebookScopedClient(string appId, string appSecret)
            {
                this.appId = appId;
                this.appSecret = appSecret;
            }

            public string ProviderName
            {
                get { return "Facebook"; }
            }

            public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
            {
                string url = baseUrl + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=email";
                context.Response.Redirect(url);
            }

            public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
            {
                string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

                string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;
                //From this we need to remove code portion
                rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

                IDictionary<string, string> userData = GetUserData(code, rawUrl);

                if (userData == null)
                    return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);

                string id = userData["id"];
                string username = userData["email"];
                userData.Remove("id");
                userData.Remove("email");

                AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, id, username, userData);
                return result;
            }
        }
```

now in the

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
```

method in `AccountController`, `result.ExtraData` should have the email.

**Edit: I missed some code in this post. I am adding it below:**

```
public static class String
    {
        public static string Substring(this string str, string StartString, string EndString)
        {
            if (str.Contains(StartString))
            {
                int iStart = str.IndexOf(StartString) + StartString.Length;
                int iEnd = str.IndexOf(EndString, iStart);
                return str.Substring(iStart, (iEnd - iStart));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: I had an issue with your "token.Substring("access_token=", "&"))" line, since Substring only accepts integers, but this helped immensely.  I decided to write a blog post explaining how to extend this a little further, but this post got me 98% there.

http://savvydev.com/authenticating-facebook-users-with-mvc-4-oauth-and-obtaining-scope-permissions/

Comment: Apologies. Forgot to include the extension class for string. Adding it to the code now.....

Comment: Thanks, Varun. I had to make a slight tweak for apps being hosted on AppHarbor (which I explain in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14567037/389899)) but you did all the hard work.

Comment: @Varun it would be great to see an update for the new v2.0 api.

Comment: @JedGrant - the code is here: https://github.com/vchatterji/OAuth2ClientCredentialGrant
(not maintaining it anymore, please feel free to fork and do whatever).

Answer (score 13):

Update your NuGet package in your MVC4 Internet project.

DotNetOpenAuthCore. It will automatically update all dependencies.

Now result.UserName will contain the email adress instead of your name.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the current user is logged in add the new account
            OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
            string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
        }
    }
```

The reason for this?

https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/a9d2443ee1a35f13c528cce35b5096abae7128f4/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OAuth2/FacebookClient.cs has been updated in latest NuGet package.

The commit with the fix:
https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/commit/a9d2443ee1a35f13c528cce35b5096abae7128f4

Comment: This is great :) many thanks, that saved me time and effort to have it customized, it's now built it as it should be ;)

Comment: @PUssInBoots.  Great instructions.  I followed them and I'm getting an email back, except it is now 'app+ecnu0tj0rd.ogrton.663c6730d07a632705b2907f0533c984@proxymail.facebook.com'  which is not what I want.  Any idea why I'm getting this long proxymail.facebook.com address?

Comment: @user576838 Never seen that kind of email in my app before. Maybe try logging in with another user with another email from another email provider, see if you get the same results.

Comment: Thank you, so glad I checked this answer before doing a whole lot of work, whew!

Comment: Updated DotNetOpenAuthCore as per the answer, but again getting the  UserName instead of user mail. Is there any changes to be made code. Like specifying scope in AuthConfig. Please help

Answer (score 2):

I used [Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13125765/389899), but I had to make a small modification to get it to work for my app being hosted on [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com).

AppHarbor has to do some funky stuff with the port number in urls to handle load balancing. You can read a little more about it [here](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/workaround-for-generating-absolute-urls-without-port-number). In short, getting the AbsoluteUri of the current request while hosting on AppHarbor may return a uri with a port number other than 80. This causes problems with Facebook authentication, because they expect your return url to be the one you specified when creating your app.

The problem comes in at `string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;` in `VerifyAuthentication()`. If you use this code, `rawUrl` may contain some port number other than 80, causing the Facebook authentication to fail. Instead, replace that line with

```
string rawUrl = GetRawUrl(context.Request.Url);
```

and add the `GetRawUrl()` function to the class:

```
public static string GetRawUrl(Uri url)
{
    var port = url.Port;
    if (SettingsHelper.GetHostingService() == HostingServices.AppHarbor)
        port = 80;

    return new UriBuilder(url)
    {
        Port = port
    }.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

You will need to replace `if (SettingsHelper.GetHostingService() == HostingServices.AppHarbor)` with your own logic for determining whether or not your application is running on AppHarbor.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own solution to this problem. I extended the OAuth2Client to take advantage of it work and used facebook scope and other features to retrieve additional user data.
I posted my own solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16234946/1771201), I hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Since FB made "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" mandatory the RewriteRequest is needed (as for Google Oauth). 
Add the call below in callback processing before OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication.

```
FacebookScopedClient.RewriteRequest();
```

FacebookScopedClient Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace UserAccounts.WebApi.ExternalLogin
{
    // Thnks to Har Kaur https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/facebook-integration-by-using-oauth and https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2/blob/master/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2/GoogleOAuth2Client.cs
    public class FacebookScopedClient : IAuthenticationClient
    {
        private string appId;
        private string appSecret;
        private static string providerName = "Facebook";

        private const string baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=";
        public const string graphApiToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
        public const string graphApiMe = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";


        private static string GetHTML(string URL)
        {
            string connectionString = URL;

            try
            {
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
                myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                //// Get the response  
                WebResponse webResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                ////  
                StreamReader ioStream = new StreamReader(respStream);
                string pageContent = ioStream.ReadToEnd();
                //// Close streams  
                ioStream.Close();
                respStream.Close();
                return pageContent;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream());
                string line;
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.Append(line);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }


        private IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessCode, string redirectURI)
        {
            string value = "";
            string token = GetHTML(graphApiToken + "client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" +
                                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURI) + "&client_secret=" +
                                       appSecret + "&code=" + accessCode);
            if (token == null || token == "")
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (token != null || token != "")
            {
                if (token.IndexOf("access_token") > -1)
                {
                    string[] arrtoken = token.Replace("\''", "").Split(':');
                    string[] arrval = arrtoken[1].ToString().Split(',');
                    value = arrval[0].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                }
            }
            string data = GetHTML(graphApiMe + "fields=id,name,email,gender,link&access_token=" + value);


            // this dictionary must contains  
            Dictionary<string, string> userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
            return userData;
        }


        public FacebookScopedClient(string appId, string appSecret)
        {
            this.appId = appId;
            this.appSecret = appSecret;
        }

        public string ProviderName
        {
            get { return providerName; }
        }

        public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(returnUrl);
            uriBuilder.Query = "";
            var newUri = uriBuilder.Uri;

            string returnUrlQuery = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.Query);
            string url = baseUrl + appId + "&scope=email" + "&state=" + returnUrlQuery + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newUri.ToString());
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }

        public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
        {
            string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

            string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;
            //From this we need to remove code portion  
            rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(rawUrl);
            uriBuilder.Query = "";
            var newUri = uriBuilder.Uri;

            IDictionary<string, string> userData = GetUserData(code, newUri.ToString());

            if (userData == null)
                return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);

            string id = userData["id"];
            string username = userData["email"];
            userData.Remove("id");
            userData.Remove("email");

            AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, id, username, userData);
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Facebook requires that all return data be packed into a "state" parameter.
        /// This should be called before verifying the request, so that the url is rewritten to support this.
        /// Thnks to Matt Johnson mj1856 https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2/blob/master/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2/GoogleOAuth2Client.cs
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public static void RewriteRequest()
        {
            var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            var stateString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ctx.Request.QueryString["state"]);
            if (stateString == null || !stateString.Contains("__provider__=" + providerName)) return;

            var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(stateString);
            q.Add(ctx.Request.QueryString);
            q.Remove("state");

            ctx.RewritePath(ctx.Request.Path + "?" + q);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem here.
The only way I found to pass the "scope" parameter to facebook was coding my own OAuth client.

To do it, you must extend and implement the abstract methods of  DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.

On the GetServiceLoginUrl method you can add the scope parameter to the url.
So, when you call the OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication() method, the AuthenticationResult.UserName provides the user's email.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OAuth2/FacebookClient.cs).

Good luck.

Comment: Well now I looked once again at the method to register facebook and it has an overload that takes some extraData parameter, but is this for the login? IDictionary<string,object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            fbParams.Add("scope", "email");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient("onekey", "anotherkey", "facebook",
                fbParams);

Comment: Wouldn't that have been thoughtful... seems like a waste to not enable "extraData" declarations in this manner. I wonder what the reasoning was for not doing it that way.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done...like this:

```
var fb = new Dictionary<string, object>();
fb.Add("scope", "email,publish_actions");
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
appId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
appSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
displayName: "FaceBook",
extraData: fb);
```

Comment: This does not work.  The "extraData" parameter is not sent to or used by Facebook.