# ASP.NET MVC 4 - DotnetOpenAuth - How to set a Facebook permissions scope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, dotnetopenauth

I like set the Facebook permissions scope. As example user_about_me and email. I find this solution in web:

```
Dictionary<String, Object> facebookPermissions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        facebookPermissions.Add("scope", "email,user_about_me");


OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(OAuthService.AppId, OAuthService.AppSecret, "facebook", facebookPermissions);
```

But doesn't work. The Facebook login doesn't show me the needed permission for my Facebook App. And the URL have no defined scope..

Comment: A custom FacebookScopedClient helps me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610402/oauthwebsecurity-with-facebook-not-using-email-permission-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

To get email address permission:

Have a look at this solution from [this post](http://tinyurl.com/aherzvm) (The post that does not marked as an answer):

"Update your NuGet package in your MVC4 Internet project. DotNetOpenAuthCore. It will automatically update all dependencies. Now result.UserName will contain the email adress instead of your name."

Answer (score -1):

The custom FacebookScopedClient was work only correct with localhost.. I upload a web project to Windows Azure Web Role and change in Facebook App the Web Role URL.. the login failed.. I need please a solution with set Facebook Login Scope with DotNetOpenAuth