# .NET ASP.NET MVC application Facebook OAuth with defined scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

What is the easiest way to create [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) application with Facebook [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) with defined scope?

I tried many examples. [OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc)  doesn't support adding more Facebook scope. [Facebook application template](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update/facebook-application-template-tutorial) creates a canvas and I need non-canvas application. FacebookScopedClient is not full and wasn't able to work with this fix.

What do you suggest?

I also open for JavaScript/jQuery solutions.

Answer (score 11):

Probably I'm too late, but I came into this problem some days ago and I found only few poor solutions on the web. So I wrote my own solution and I can post it only now.

I took advantage of the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client class which do the most of the job. I only extended that to include scope and extra user data.

```
public class FacebookExtendedClient : DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client
{   
    protected FacebookClient facebookClient;
    protected string fields;
    protected string scope;
    protected Func<string, object, string> fieldTransformer;
    protected bool emailAsUsername;
    protected IDictionary<string, string> userData;

    private string[] splittedFields;
    private string[] splittedScope;

    protected const string serviceLoginBaseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
    protected const string serviceMeBaseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
    protected const string serviceAccessTokenBaseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instrance of the class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appId">The App ID of the application used to connect to Facebook service.</param>
    /// <param name="appSecret">The App Secret of the application used to connect to Facebook service.</param>
    /// <param name="fields">
    /// String containing comma separated fields to add to the request.
    /// If empty the request will retrieve the default fields based of the specified scope.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="fieldTransformer">
    /// Function to be applied to the values retrived from facebook.
    /// If null provided the method will try to cast values from object to string explicitly,
    /// an InvalidCastException will be thrown if the cast will not be possible.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="scope">
    /// String containing comma separated permissions to add to the request.
    /// If empty the request will have the basic scope.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="emailAsUsername">Makes the email of the facebook user used as authentication username.</param>
    public FacebookExtendedClient(string appId, string appSecret, string fields = "", Func<string, object, string> fieldTransformer = null, string scope = "", bool emailAsUsername = false)
        : base("facebook")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appId))
            throw new ArgumentException("The appId argument can not be null or empty.", "appId");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appSecret))
            throw new ArgumentException("The appSecret argument can not be null or empty.", "appSecret");

        fields = fields.Replace(" ", "");
        scope = scope.Replace(" ", "");
        this.splittedFields = fields.Split(',');
        this.splittedScope = scope.Split(',');

        if (emailAsUsername == true && !this.splittedFields.Contains("email") && !this.splittedScope.Contains("email"))
            throw new ArgumentException("The scope argument must contain the 'email' permission and the 'email' field to allow emailAsUsername to true.", "scope");

        this.facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
        this.facebookClient.AppId = appId;
        this.facebookClient.AppSecret = appSecret;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.fieldTransformer = fieldTransformer;
        this.scope = scope;
        this.emailAsUsername = emailAsUsername;
    }

    public FacebookClient FacebookClient
    {
        get
        {
            return this.facebookClient;
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> UserData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userData;
        }
    }

    protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("redirect_uri", returnUrl.AbsoluteUri);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.scope))
            parameters.Add("scope", this.scope);

        return this.facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
    {
        // This method makes the AuthenticationResult's UserName property be the facebook username of the logged user,
        // but if the facebook username is missing the facebook id will be used.
        // If emailAsUsername is true then AuthenticationResult's UserName property is the email retrieved from facebook
        // and the facebook username can be retrieved by the key "fb_username" in this.userData

        FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        var getResult = facebookClient.Get<IDictionary<string, object>>("me", new { fields = this.fields });
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (this.fieldTransformer != null)
        {
            foreach (var pair in getResult)
                result.Add(pair.Key, this.fieldTransformer(pair.Key, pair.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var pair in getResult)
            {
                string value = pair.Value.ToString();

                if (value == null)
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Cast not possible for the object associate to the key '" + pair.Key + "'.");

                result.Add(pair.Key, value);
            }
        }

        if (this.splittedFields.Contains("username"))
            result["fb_username"] = result["username"];

        if (this.emailAsUsername)
            result["username"] = result["email"];

        this.userData = result;

        return result;
    }

    protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
    {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(serviceAccessTokenBaseUrl);
        builder.Query = string.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&redirect_uri={2}&code={3}",
            this.facebookClient.AppId, this.facebookClient.AppSecret, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri)), authorizationCode);

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string str = client.DownloadString(builder.Uri);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                return null;

            return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(str)["access_token"];
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as well registering it in OAuthWebSecurity like this (put RegisterAuth method in Application_Start, like it is in the InternetApplication template):

```
public static class AuthConfig
{
    public static void RegisterAuth()
    {
        configuration.LoadFromAppSettings();

        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookExtendedClient(
            "##YOUR_APP_ID##",
            "##YOUR_APP_SECRET##",
            "id,first_name,last_name,link,username,gender,email,age_range,picture.height(200)",
            new Func<string, object, string>(fieldsTransformer),
            "email"));
    }

    private static string fieldsTransformer(string key, object value)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case "picture":
                var data = (value as IDictionary<string, object>)["data"] as IDictionary<string, object>;
                return data["url"].ToString();
            case "age_range":
                var min = (value as IDictionary<string, object>)["min"];
                return min.ToString();
            default:
                return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example above the method fieldsTransformer will get the key and the value foreach field selected, in this case it will transform the object retrived by facebook for the picture into the url of the picture. This is a convenience method, if null is provided for the Func parameter, the JSON representation of the values object will be saved.

Retrieve the client information later, after the login, can be done like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> userData = (OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData("facebook").AuthenticationClient as FacebookExtendedClient).UserData;
        string email = userData["email"];

        // If leave null the fieldTransform of the client you can access to complex properties like this:
        JObject picture = JObject.Parse(userData["picture"]);
        string url = (picture["data"] as JObject)["url"].ToString();

        ViewBag.Email = userData["email"];
        ViewBag.PictureUrl = url;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Hope you enjoy this code, even if it is a bit late! :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Dunadan. What's the namespace for FacebookClient in the FacebookExtendedClient class? If I use the suggested DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients namespace I get a load of syntax errors for uses of FacebookClient.

Comment: Ah it's the Facebook client available via NuGet.

Comment: Yes, be aware of use the correct assembly: the FacebookClient is the one into Facebook package, not DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients, they unfortunaly has the same name.

Comment: I like this approach and used something very similar before seeing this post. My concern is if your application requires different permissions at different times during different user scenarios how do you parameterize that without getting a proliferation of OAuth2Client sub classses each initialized with different scope?

Comment: @Dunadan, in a MVC 4 project I implemented it like that, 1st of all to show "Facebook" in the button name (@p.Displayname), in _ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml the following adjustment is needed in the AuthConfig.cs file: OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookExtendedClient(..."email"), "Facebook", null); 2nd: the code you added in the HomeController/Index (as testing I guess) has to be put/customized in Accountcontroller/ExternalLoginCallback . That said thx very much for your code, I quite liked this implementation!

Answer (score 1):

I am writing my first Facebook app with C# MVC 5 web app in VS 2013.

In the AppStart\StartupAuth.cs file, I made the following modifications.

Ensure the following using statements are in the class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;
using Owin;`
```

Then, in the Facebook authentication section near the bottom of the ConfigureAuth method:

```
FacebookAuthenticationOptions fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
fbOptions.AppId="YOUR_APP_ID";
fbOptions.AppSecret="YOUR_APP_SECRET";
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_about_me");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_actions.books");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_actions.music");
//...more at the bottom
fbOptions.Scope.Add("video_upload");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("xmpp_login");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbOptions);
```

That's it!  Below is the full list as of 2/1/2014:

```
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_about_me");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_actions.books");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_actions.music");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_actions.news");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_actions.video");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_activities");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_checkins");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_education_history");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_events");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_friends");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_games_activity");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_groups");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_hometown");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_interests");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_likes");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_location");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_notes");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_online_presence");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_photo_video_tags");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_photos");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_questions");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_relationship_details");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_relationships");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_religion_politics");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_status");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_subscriptions");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_videos");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_website");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_work_history");

fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_about_me");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_actions.books");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_actions.music");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_actions.news");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_actions.video");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_activities");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_birthday");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_checkins");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_education_history");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_events");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_games_activity");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_groups");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_hometown");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_interests");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_likes");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_location");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_notes");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_online_presence");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_photo_video_tags");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_photos");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_questions");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_relationship_details");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_relationships");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_religion_politics");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_status");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_subscriptions");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_videos");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_website");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("friends_work_history");

fbOptions.Scope.Add("ads_management");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("ads_read");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("create_event");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("create_note");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("email");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("export_stream");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("manage_friendlists");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("manage_notifications");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("manage_pages");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("photo_upload");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("publish_actions");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("publish_checkins");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("publish_stream");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("read_friendlists");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("read_insights");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("read_mailbox");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("read_page_mailboxes");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("read_requests");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("read_stream");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("rsvp_event");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("share_item");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("sms");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("status_update");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("video_upload");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("xmpp_login");
```