# MVC 4 OAuth integration. What is next and how to get any information from data provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

I found a lot of posts and articles with very detailed information about how to configure MVC 4 application to be integrated with any social network provider and how to authenticate users, but what's next? How to get any information about authenticated user, for example? The simplest task that coming to my head how to get some information about authenticated user -  first name, last name, avatar's url, friends list etc.?

**Update:**

1. Here is some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610402/oauthwebsecurity-with-facebook-not-using-email-permission-as-expected) and [article](http://savvydev.com/authenticating-facebook-users-with-mvc-4-oauth-and-obtaining-scope-permissions/) that share some light
2. Useful [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) how to interact with Facebook

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OAuth is for authenticating only, i.e. getting an access token. Once you get this access token you could use it to retrieve this information from the service provider. Consult the documentation of the provider to see how this could be done.

There are some claims you might retrieve though such as FirstName and LastName because they are standard and most providers support them. For example inside the `ExternalLoginCallback` callback you could attempt to retrieve this information from the `result.ExtraData` dictionary:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    if (!result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
    }

    if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Here you could use result.ExtraData dictionary
        string name = result.ExtraData["name"];


        // If the current user is logged in add the new account
        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
        string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
        ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
    }
}
```

But the different providers might use different keys. So depending on the provider that was used you will have to use the proper key to read the desired information.

Comment: Hi Darian, thanks a lot for the prompt response on Saturday! :) Yes, I'm aware about how to communicate with the social providers using their API but what I can't figure out at the moment how to attach access token to the request. Do I have to prepare the request manually or there are already existing classes in the framework that I could use?

Comment: The different providers might provide SDKs which could help you in achieving this task. Check the documentation of your service provider to see if it offers an SDK for a .NET client. If it doesn't you could always perform the request manually by sending an HTTP request to the corresponding endpoint. You will of course have to check the documentation to see where exactly does the API expects to send the access token. The different providers have different implementations.